# Access xaml control inside ith item in flipview

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, datatemplate, flipview

I have a flipview which is populated by some code (I don't understand how modifying an app).

```
<FlipView  x:Name="ArticleDetail" Grid.Row="1" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView" AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details" TabIndex="1"
             DataContext="{Binding LatestArticlesModel}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LatestArticles1DetailDetail}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FlipItemStyle}">
</FlipView>

<!--Data template for flipview-->
<DataTemplate x:Key="LatestArticles1DetailDetail">
      <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
             <TextBlock Margin="0,16" 
                  Text="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource    TextPlainConverter}, ConverterParameter = 140}" 
                  Style="{StaticResource SubHeaderText}" />
              <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource ThumbnailConverter},      ConverterParameter=300}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
              <TextBlock 
                   x:Name="FeedUrl" 
                   Margin="0,12"  Style="{StaticResource Html2XamlStyleText}"
                   Text="{Binding FeedUrl}" 
                   Visibility="Collapsed"/>
              <RichTextBlock 
                    x:Name="Content" 
                    Margin="0,12"  
                    Style="{StaticResource Html2XamlStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
</DataTemplate>
```

From the textblock named "FeedUrl" I want to extract the url which is stored in it.

Use the url to parse the html page pointed to by that url

After processing display some content in the richtextblock named "content".

The only problem I am facing in it is how to get reference to the textblock and richtextblock inside each item of the flipview.

For getting reference to items I have tried two solutions:

---

1. I've tried this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799412/access-to-controls-inside-a-flipview-un-xaml) but the line

`var myTextBlock= _Children.OfType<TextBlock>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name.Equals("test"));` specifically

`.OfType<TextBlock>()` gives an error

`'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock>' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

---

2. I also tried another solution given [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17502.finding-element-in-itemscontrol-datatemplate-listviewgridviewflipview-window-store-apps.aspx), but I always get a null reference.

I also get a warning for the line

`var item = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(o); 
Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(o); is obsolote.'ContainerForm' may be unavailable for releases after Windows Phone 8.1. Use itemsControl.ContainerFromItem instead.`

Even if I use `itemsControl.ContainerFromItem` it always returns a null reference.

Please Help

---

UPDATE:

I'm using the following

```
if(!statusiop.statusup){
this.UpdateLayout();
for (int i = 0; i < ArticleDetail.Items.Count; i++)
{
var fvItem = this.ArticleDetail.Items[i];
var container = this.ArticleDetail.ContainerFromItem(fvItem);
 if (container == null)
 {
     Text = "null container";
 }
 else
 {
     var tbFeedURL = FindElementByName<TextBlock>(container, "FeedUrl");
     if (tbFeedURL == null)
     {
         test.Text = "null text";
     }
     else
     {
         tbFeedURL.Text = tbFeedURL.Text + "Test";
     }
 } 
}
```

I iterate through all the items in the flipview, and modify the data as needed. I am also using a public static class

```
public static class statusiop
{
    public static Boolean statusup= false;

}
```

which contains a member statusup. statusup serves as a flag which when true indicates that the flipview data has been updated once and need not be updated again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a VisualTreeHelper method. This is just some code I am using. I think you can easily adjust it to your needs.

First put the FindElementByName method somewhere into your code behind file:

```
public T FindElementByName<T>(DependencyObject element, string sChildName) where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        T childElement = null;
        var nChildCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
        for (int i = 0; i < nChildCount; i++)
        {
            FrameworkElement child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as FrameworkElement;

            if (child == null)
                continue;

            if (child is T && child.Name.Equals(sChildName))
            {
                childElement = (T)child;
                break;
            }

            childElement = FindElementByName<T>(child, sChildName);

            if (childElement != null)
                break;
        }
        return childElement;
    }
```

Now you can start using the method:

```
this.UpdateLayout();
var fvItem = this.ArticleDetail.Items[ArticleDetail.SelectedIndex];
var container = this.ArticleDetail.ContainerFromItem(fvItem);
// NPE safety, deny first
if (container == null)
    return;
var tbFeedURL = FindElementByName<TextBlock>(container, "FeedUrl");
// And again deny if we got null
if (tbFeedURL == null)
    return;
/*
  Start doing your stuff here.
*/
```

Comment: `var container = this.ArticleDetail.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(fvItem);
` is giving a warning
`Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(Object); is obsolote.'ContainerForm' may be unavailable for releases after Windows Phone 8.1. Use itemsControl.ContainerFromItem instead.`

Null reference is returned to container variable.

Comment: Try calling `UpdateLayout()`beforehand. And I replaced the obsolete calls with the current ones. Tell me if it works now.

Comment: It's working partially. Out of 10 items in the flipview. Only two are updated and the rest are not. Even I tried using a loop from i=0 to Article.Items.Count-1 and then used var fvItem = this.ArticleDetail.Items[i]; But even then only first two items are updated. Plus I'm unable to move through items in the list in either case

Comment: You might want to update your question with your code. It's hard to help when there is no code to inspect.

Comment: I've updated question with the code, please review it. The problems are the same as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Where do you call that method? Is the Flipboard data really fully loaded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62615/discussion-between-user3263192-and-fred).

Comment: Works when calling the function inside `SelectionChanged EventHandler`.
Instead of using
`var fvItem = this.ArticleDetail.Items[ArticleDetail.SelectedIndex];`
I used
`FlipView ArticleDetailSelectedItem = sender as FlipView;
var fvItem = ArticleDetailSelectedItem.SelectedItem;`

Thanks for helping me out.