# Get Data Template Element from List View (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

Is there anyway to access the data template elements from the holded listview item, when onholding event is occurred?

My aim is to make the testGrid visible when the user holded the item.

```
<ListView x:Name="groupsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding groupListShow.GroupingList}" Margin="15,0,15,70" ItemClick="groupsListView_ItemClick" Holding="groupsListView_Holding" >
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                          <Grid x:Name="testGrid" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="{StaticResource LightBG}" Margin="0">
....
```

Any help?

```
    private void groupsListView_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //How can I get child elements from these codes?
        FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement; 

        Object contGrid = e.OriginalSource;
    }
```

Comment: This should be the code you're looking for, just modify it for your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236707/access-xaml-control-inside-ith-item-in-flipview/26237483#26237483

Comment: Thanks @Fred. VisualTreeHelper class solved my problem.