# Changing properties of controls inside a longlist selector

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone

In my app, I am trying to change the property of a button inside the longlist selector which is inside a pivot item. I tried using " x:Name " to name the button, which I could further use in the event handler but an error occurs "The Name does not exist in the current context."
I have used the same method to modify properties of the longlist selector and it worked fine.

Here's my XAML code:

```
<phone:PivotItem x:Name="settingPivotItem">
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="longList3" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding extra.Items}" 
                                SelectionChanged="longList3_SelectionChanged">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="settingButton">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding item}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
      </phone:LongListSelector>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

Please Help

Comment: Use a VisualTreeHelper to retrieve UI elements from a DataTemplate. Here is a sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236707/access-xaml-control-inside-ith-item-in-flipview/26237483#26237483

Comment: I tried the solution in the above link but I can't find an alternative of ContainerFromItem for LongListSelector as LongListSelector does not have it.

Answer (score 0):

The Button you are trying to access it inside a data-template and therefore in a different context.

You cannot access it by it's x:Name from outside the template, because the there can be multiple items with that template (so there could be multiple buttons with that name).

If you really have to change it's properties from code, you can use the VisualTreeHelper, als Fred stated.

Other option would to us a databinding.

Comment: I tried using databinding but when I set the data context of the button the the list doesn't populate probably because I am using an item source in the LongListSelector and binding one of its attribute to the TextBlock as well.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't make any sense if that comment. Where exactly do you want to change properties of the button?

Comment: Well, in my app when I swipe among the pivot items, I want the alignment of the items(inside the LongListSelector) in this particular pivot item to change depending on from where I swipe(left or right). I was able to change the horizontal alignment of the LongListSelector but for the text to completely align to the other side, I need to change the horizontal alignment of the button as well. Now, I have the condition for from where the pivot item was navigated to(left or right), all I need is a way to access that button inside that condition.