# Windows Store App - XAML UI element not visible in C# code

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, microsoft-metro

I have the following XAML code and the only element available in the C# code behind are the Grid and the FlipView. How can I make the ScrollViewer, Image or the Viewbox visibile in the code?

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridViewPages">
        <FlipView x:Name="FlipView1" Loaded="FlipView1_Loaded" Style="{StaticResource FlipViewPreviewIndicator}" Tapped="FlipView1_Tapped">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="pagesScrollViewer" ZoomMode="Enabled"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                    MinZoomFactor="1.0"
                                    MaxZoomFactor="3.0"
                                    Margin="0"
                                    Width="1500" DoubleTapped="PagesScrollViewer_DoubleTapped">
                        <Viewbox x:Name="pagesViewbox">
                            <Image Source="{Binding}"
                               Height="730"
                               x:Name="pageImage" Stretch="Uniform" Loaded="MainImage_Loaded"/>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>  
        </FlipView>
    </Grid>
```

The flipview is customized and contains also a listview defined in  which is not visible in the code too...:

```
<Page.Resources>
 ...
<ListView x:Name="pagesPreview" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto"
                                              ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                                              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                                              Background="AliceBlue"
                                              Opacity="1" 
                                              SelectionChanged="pagesPreview_SelectionChanged"
                                              Visibility="Visible">
                                        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                    <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListView>
 ...
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: share you code. then only we can able to answer you

Answer (score 0):

See the basic concept of the flipview is to have multiple pages to have a flip effect. So whatever the Data template contains is repeated multiple times. So if you want the x:Name to come up then you wont have any success.

There are two ways As per my knowledge :

VisualTreeHelper -> for a better detail of it go through this link

[Get elements from data template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375375/how-do-i-access-a-control-inside-a-xaml-datatemplate)

you can manually iterate over the flipview elements and track down the children of the flipview. Try that in debug mode you'll get a fair idea of what comes after what. Just keep track of the element at which selected index position you want modified

Thanks.