# Access Data Inside HubSection

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

Please, help me:

If I have a TextBox in a HubSection, how I can get data from it if the Grid that I have the TextBox is in a DataTemplate?,

```
<Hub Style="{StaticResource HubStyle1}">
    <Hub.Header>
    <!-- Some stuff here -->
    </Hub.Header>

    <HubSection Width="731" Style="{StaticResource HubSectionStyle1}">
       <DataTemplate>
           <Grid  FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Margin=" 0,10,0,0" >

               <TextBox  
                   Grid.Row="0" 
                   Grid.Column="1"     
                   Style="{StaticResource AddTextBlockStyle}"    />

           </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

Answer (score 4):

handle the `Loaded` event for any of the elements and the sender parameter will be that element.  Save the parameter for later access.

Answer (score 0):

Go through This question 
[How do I access a control inside a XAML DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375375/how-do-i-access-a-control-inside-a-xaml-datatemplate)

if you are trying to acccess element inside template