# How to access controls inside HubSection in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, json, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am using a HubSection as below:

```
<HubSection Header="Section1">
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBox />
  </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>

<HubSection Header="Section1">
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBox />
  </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>

<HubSection Header="Section1">
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBox />
  </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

Now I am having a JSON from which I want to bind the textboxes inside all the `HubSection`

Below is the class for the JSON data:

```
class RootObject
{
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    public string Text2 { get; set; }
    public string Text3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846807/access-data-inside-hubsection) question and [this](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/winrt-xaml-hub-control-getting-started-tutorial-semanticzoom) article, I can very well use the `Loaded` event for the `TextBox` as below and set the value.

```
<TextBox Loaded="TextBox_Loaded" />

private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var txtBox = (TextBox)sender;
    txtBox.Text = "Some Text";
}
```

But the problem is that it will not be good to do so if I have few more controls to bind/access inside each of the `HubSection`.

So can someone please tell me if there is another simple way to bind the controls.

Comment: You could use [Stack Panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel.aspx) in your Data Template and add controls to the Stack Panel. In this way, you can have more controls to bind or access inside each of the HubSection.

Comment: @MattewWu-MSFT But still I have three `HubSection`s and I want to bind all the controls in all the `HubSection` from a single object like here `RootObject`.

Comment: @DeepakSharma Do you want to generate the `HubSections` dynamically or is it a defined count of 3?

Comment: @rbr94 It is a defined count. All I want is to bind all the controls inside all of the `HubSection` from my `RootObject` class defined above.

Comment: @DeepakSharma If I understand you correctly. That means that you want to bind the first `TextBox.Text` property to `Text1` of `RootObject`, the second to `Text2` and so on? Do you want to use `RootObject` to fill the textboxes or do you want to do it the other way?

Comment: @rbr94 `That means that you want to bind the first TextBox.Text property to Text1 of RootObject, the second to Text2 and so on?`  YES. Thats exactly what I want. And yes I want to use `RootObject` as that is what I am parsing the JSON into.

Comment: @DeepakSharma Could I help you?

Comment: @rbr94 I am yet to try out your solution. Will do today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope This Helps

**C#**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        RootObject ro = new RootObject() {Text1 = "Header1JsonData",Text2= "Header2JsonData",Text3= "Header3JsonData"};
        this.DataContext = ro;

    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    public string Text2 { get; set; }
    public string Text3 { get; set; }
}
```

}

---

**XAML**

```
   <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Hub >
        <HubSection Header="Section1">
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox  Text="{Binding Text1}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection Header="Section1">
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text2}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection Header="Section1">
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox  Text="{Binding Text3}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
</Grid>
```

---

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**C#:**

In the code behind class (e.g. a `Page`) you need to define a property containing the `RootObject`. Note that you maybe need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to react to a change of this property value.

```
public Page1 : Page {
    public RootObject RootObject { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML:**

In your XAML you then should simply use bindings to the properties of `RootObject` like this:

```
<HubSection Header="Section1">
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding RootObject.Text1}" />
  </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>

<HubSection Header="Section2">
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding RootObject.Text2}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```