# Create a custom template as ResourceDictionary and access it from codebehind

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, datatemplate, resourcedictionary

I need to create a simple CRUD, and i want to reuse the same "template" in different pages.

MyCrud.xaml (the template)

```
<ResourceDictionary 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<!-- disegno la mia crud-->
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyCrud">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,20">
            <TextBlock Text="Code"  FontWeight="Bold" Width="150" FontSize="24"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="edtCode" InputScope="Number" Width="300" Margin="20,0,20,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,20">
            <TextBlock Text="Vin" FontWeight="Bold" Width="150" FontSize="24"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="edtVin" Width="300" Margin="20,0,20,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,20">
            <TextBlock Text="Url" FontWeight="Bold" Width="150" FontSize="24"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="edtUrl" Width="300" Margin="20,0,20,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then I registered it in my App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="View/MyCrud.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

So now I want to put it in a page, and use it in my SearchPage.xaml

SearchPage.xaml

```
<Page ...bla bla bla>
<ContentControl x:Name="MyTemplate" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyCrud}" />
</Page>
```

At the moment the Layout works perfectly

The questions are:

1. How can I access the `TextBox`?  For example the one called
   `edtVin` from codebehind of SearchPage.
2. Why is `TextBox p= GetTemplateChild("edtVin") as TextBox;` always null?
3. I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676690/accessing-controls-on-datatemplate-from-datatemplates-code-behind), is it the best one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> *"Create a proper ViewModel and use proper DataBinding and all your
>   problems will magically disappear."*

A `DataTemplate` is intended to be used as a *"Visual Representation of a Certain Data Element"*.

There is **no need** to "access" any UI elements in procedural code in WPF. Whatever modifications to any properties of these elements should be done using proper [**DataBinding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), otherwise, if you manually modify the UI elements' properties (without modifying the corresponding underlying *Data Item*), you are basically breaking the consistency between UI and Data, and the UI elements inside the DataTemplate will no longer reflect the data inside the *Data Item*.

Create a simple class that represents the Data you want to show on screen:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Code {get;set;}

    public string Vin {get;set;}

    public string Url {get;set;}
}
```

Then, in order to support two-way WPF DataBinding, have your class [Implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Then, set the UI's [**DataContext**](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/) to a relevant instance (or collection) of these items:

```
public MyWindow() //Window's constructor
{
   InitializeComponent();

   var list = new List<MyData>();

   //... populate the list with data here...

   DataContext = list;
}
```

and then simply manipulate these Data Items's properties while leaving the UI alone:

```
var item = list[0]; //for example

item.Code = "My New Code";
```

**This is the correct way to work with WPF.**

Answer (score 1):

> 1) how can i access to the TextBox, for example the one called
>   "edtVin" from codebehind of SearchPage?

You can get like this:

```
MyTemplate.ContentTemplate.FindName("edtVin", MyTemplate) as TextBox;
```

> 2) why TextBox p= GetTemplateChild("edtVin") as TextBox;

This returns null since `edtVin` is template child of ContentControl and not of Page.

> 3) i found that solution, is it the best one?

Yeah you can also use `VisualTreeHelper` methods as well. Add them as utility functions in your project so that it can be accessed from anywhere in the code.

Comment: `MyTemplate.ContentTemplate`doesn't have any methods like `FindName` o Find-something

Comment: You are talking about `WPF` here? Right? Method do exists, you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname(v=vs.110).aspx). Compiling fine at my end.

Comment: i'm trying to create a Windows Store App, previously i choose the wrong tag

Comment: `VisualTreeHelper` is a way to go for it then. Refer to answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16446670/632337) OR the one you provided in the link is a way to go.