# Can't access ComboBox in DataGridTemplateColumn (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have following code in xaml:

```
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="120">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="_status" ItemsSource="{Binding status}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Can someone explain me why i can't access _status ComboBox? I'm trying to assign it to:

```
_status.ItemsSource = statuses.jobStatus();
```

Comment: `_status` can just be accessed inside the CellTemplate, the current context in codebehind is out of that scope. Please use some pattern here, use Binding instead of setting the ItemsSource like that.

Comment: how can i bind it to method in another class then? Not experienced with xaml that much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and found that article.
May be useful to someone. Easy to use!

http://www.dev102.com/2008/08/07/how-to-access-a-wpf-control-which-is-located-in-a-datatemplate/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then the problem is that the `Name` property of `_status` is not visible because it would conflict with the previous or the next sibling of the DataTemplate that was generated. Full description is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375375/how-do-i-access-a-control-inside-a-xaml-datatemplate/16446670#16446670).