# Access StoryBoard defined in GridView DataTemplate for specific instance of GridViewItem

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp, storyboard

Ok so I have a GridView with a DataTemplate and the ItemSource set to Binding. The GridView is populated perfectly and I have no issues there.

My problem is as follows

1. User taps on an image inside the DataTemplate
2. A Flyout is displayed showing a simple ListView of the GridView items (works)
3. User taps on a ListView item inside the flyout
4. The GridView item matching the ListView item is then updated (works fine)
5. A StoryBoard should be started (doesn't work)

The idea is that one player has attacked another player and I would like an animation to be started on the attacked player, but I can only access the attacking player using (sender).

The storyboard is defined within the GridViewItem DataTemplate, I can access this if that GridViewItem was tapped by using the sender and .Find() However I cannot use this I want to start a storyboard on a GridViewItem that hasn't been tapped.

I had a thought that maybe the Storyboard could be written inside the class used for the GridViewItem Bindings? How then would this be done?

Or maybe use a DataTrigger, but can this be used when the value I want to check against is and int being reduced?

Comment: Can you give some image and your code to help us to know?

Comment: I have taken the dev in a different direction now, but I would like to know for future reference.
Triggering a storyboard in a different object instance than the one being acted upon?
The .FindName and .Resources wont work that I know of?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Resources["MyStoryboard"] as Storyboard` to get the `Storyboard` which is defined inside the `DataTemplate`. Also, use the `ContainerFromIndex` to get the item from the index.

Here is a code sample

In XAML

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Name="MyGrid">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="MyStoryboard"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        ....
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

In Code Behind

```
private void StartStoryboard(int index)
{
    var MyGridViewItem = MyGridView.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    Storyboard MyStoryboard = MyGridViewItem.Resources["MyStoryboard"] as Storyboard;
    MyStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

Now you can use `StartStoryboard(index)` to start the `Storyboard` when ever you want.

Comment: Could you please explain how this can be used to answer my question - access a Storyboard in a GridViewItem that hasn't been tapped (is NOT the sender) ?

Comment: @Sam.Pain My answer will work correctly for your case. I have added my explanation.

Comment: Hi I don't need a storyboard when the item is loaded or added. Just in general so it could be the 3rd item out of 5.

Comment: Unless I stored each storyboard when it's loaded and then referenced it. Maybe have a class property defined and add the storyboard when it's loaded?

Comment: @Sam.Pain When do you want to start storyboard? and Which storyboard to be started?

Comment: Ok. Inside gridview there are 5 instances. User taps the 2nd item which shows a fly out  user then taps an item in the fly out. This should start a storyboard on the 4th item in the gridview. For example

Comment: So you will have the Index and you want to animate the corresponding storyboard. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah that's right. Will the class need a storyboard property?

Comment: @Sam.Pain Change your selection to the corresponding index and try using the sender from the selection changed event to start storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I access a control inside a XAML DataTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375375/how-do-i-access-a-control-inside-a-xaml-datatemplate)

the link above talks about a similar issue, using the FindControl function worked a charm