# Retreive stackpanel children from GridViewItem (UWP)

Tags: c#, listview, gridview, uwp, stackpanel

I'm wondering how I can get the contents of a stackpanel which has been added to a GridViewItem (YouTube data API, the stackpanel contains a bitmap image for a thumbnail, the title of the video and a hidden TextBlock with the video ID for reference).

To clarify, I need to be able to obtain the contents of the StackPanel that is contained in the GridViewItem (such as the string of that hidden TextBox) so I can use the data to display the correct video.

Here's the code I use to create the stackpanel.

```
    public async Task SearchByKeyword(string searchTerm)
    {
        GeneralFunctions gf = new GeneralFunctions();
        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = gf.YouTubeAPIKey,
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        });

        var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.Q = searchTerm; // Replace with your search term.
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
        searchListRequest.SafeSearch = SearchResource.ListRequest.SafeSearchEnum.Strict;

        // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
        var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        List<string> videos = new List<string>();
        List<string> channels = new List<string>();
        List<string> playlists = new List<string>();

        // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
        // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
        foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
        {
            switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
            {
                case "youtube#video":

                    // Create a new StackPanel to insert as a ListViewItem
                    StackPanel sPanel = new StackPanel();
                    sPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                    sPanel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
                    sPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
                    sPanel.Width = 160;
                    sPanel.Height = 160;

                    // Create new StackPanel "Child" elements with alignment and width
                    TextBlock tb1 = new TextBlock();
                    tb1.Text = searchResult.Snippet.Title;
                    tb1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWholeWords;
                    tb1.Width = 160;

                    // Create new StackPanel "Child" elements with alignment and width
                    TextBlock tb2 = new TextBlock();
                    tb2.Text = searchResult.Snippet.ChannelId;
                    tb2.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWholeWords;
                    tb2.Width = 160;

                    // Create new StackPanel child element for a 120x120 thumbnail of the videos from the search results
                    Image image = new Image();
                    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(searchResult.Snippet.Thumbnails.Default__.Url, UriKind.Absolute));

                    // Add a "hidden" child element to each stackpanel to hold the video identity
                    TextBlock h1 = new TextBlock();
                    h1.Text = searchResult.Id.VideoId.ToString();
                    h1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    h1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWholeWords;

                    sPanel.Children.Add(image);
                    sPanel.Children.Add(tb1);
                    sPanel.Children.Add(tb2);
                    sPanel.Children.Add(h1);

                    SearchResults.Items.Add(sPanel);

                    break;

                case "youtube#channel":
                    //SearchResults.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
                    break;

                case "youtube#playlist":
                    //playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
                    break;
            }
        }



        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Videos:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", videos)));
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Channels:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", channels)));
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Playlists:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", playlists)));
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375375/how-do-i-access-a-control-inside-a-xaml-datatemplate)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I should never code tired right? The answer to my own question is actually very very simple

```
        if (SearchResults.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            StackPanel sp = (StackPanel)SearchResults.SelectedItem;

            TextBlock tb1 = (TextBlock)sp.Children[1];
            TextBlock tb2 = (TextBlock)sp.Children[2];
            TextBlock hf1 = (TextBlock)sp.Children[3];
        }
```