# UWP: DataGrid + ProgressRing

Tags: uwp, datagrid, xamarin.uwp, windows-community-toolkit

> Error  CS0103  The name 'Status' does not exist in the current context

What is the correct syntax in order to make the controller be available in the .cs file?

```xml
<controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="OrderId">
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ContextFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Copy" Icon="Copy" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Copy" />
                        <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" Icon="Delete" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Delete" />
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </Grid.ContextFlyout>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderId}" />
                <ProgressRing x:Name="Status" Foreground="Green" IsActive="True" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggested that you'd better use [Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart) to control the `IsActive` property value of ProgressRing. Then you do not need to get the control instance in code-behind.

```
<ProgressRing x:Name="Status" Foreground="Green" IsActive="{Binding xxx}" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375375/how-do-i-access-a-control-inside-a-xaml-datatemplate  what's the proper way of getting the parentContainer for the row? var pRing = FindControl<ProgressRing>(dataGrid, "Status");
pRing.IsActive = false;

Comment: @JamesEllis Have you checked my reply? I suggested you to use Binding. Why did you still want to get the control in DataTemplate? It's not a best practice.

Comment: So if you bind the progress ring what would the best approach be to mimic time delay so that the progress status is shown?

Comment: @JamesEllis Did you mean that your data is loaded so fast that your progress only shows a short time? The users hardly see ProgressRing, right?

Comment: See [Code Sample](https://github.com/Scnck/POC_Basket) trying to determine best appoarch. I want to copy/delete rows within DataGrid while showing a progressRing and mimic time delay. I want the logic to follow best practice. Thank you

Comment: You used `await Task.Delay(randomNumber);` to mimic time delay to make the ProgressRing show a little time. Then, the user can see it and know someone item has been copied/deleted. Not bad. You could use it. But I don't think you need to deliberately simulate a time-consuming operation to display the ProgressRing control. I think what users want is to save as much time as possible. You don't have to sacrifice the user experience in order to display the ProgressRing control.

Comment: If you just want to let the users know someone item has been copied/deleted successfully. You could show a [InAppNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/inappnotification) when the operation is finished.

Comment: This project is just a proof of concept, I'm more looking at the proper way of handling blinding/DataGrid what is the correct way of handling the progressRing start/finish so that I can have multiple copy/deletes running and the progress indicator would be handled correctly?

Comment: Currently "seleted.isLoading = true;" doesn't automatically refresh the DataGrid.

Comment: @JamesEllis There's no relationship between 'seleted.isLoading = true' and 'automatically refresh the DataGrid'. If you want to refresh the DataGrid, you need to refresh the ItemsSource.